# Title of crystal report- can concatinate?

Tags: crystal-reports

I wanted to find out if there is a possibility to concatenate parameters for the title?

for example:

i have parameter of sysdate and my title of the report is Chani Test i want to see in the title

Chani Test 6.11.2018

is it possible?

I waiting for your answer

regards,

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can add a textbox and place it where you want the title to show (Remove current title).  Then in the textbox type 'Chani Test', add a space and finally drag you sysdate parameter inside the textbox along with the title you just typed

In the image below, you can see the edges of the textbox and my text inside it.  Please ignore my Year parameter.

[image: See sample].